# Product moment of inertia coordinate system and sign

Tags: calculus, integration

Let's say we have an ordinary Oxy coordinate system with x pointing to the right and y pointing upwards. I have seen some people to write the product moment of inertia as : $Ixy=Iyx=-\int_{A}^{}xydA$ instead of  $\int_{A}^{}xydA$.
Why is that?